# How to export audio as a tones (ringtone) in iOS

Tags: ios, ringtone

Can anybody tell me is this possible to programmatically export audio to tones (ringtone)? Because I want to export custom audio file as ringtone.

Does Apple support this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Describe your issue and setup more detailed. iOS/MacOS? Where do you want to export it to (Desktop, straight to use on iPhone...). See how to ask right, so sou get good answers fast here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

That's not allowed in iOS. Still you can done with 3rd party libraries but apple will **reject any app that does this kind of behavior**. You might be able to save audio so that user can access them if he want can set ringtone manually.

To save audio file Refer:

[Record audio and save permanently in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078777/5215474)